# Properties after setting always nil

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring version 3.0.6 in Eclipse on osx and don't understand why I can't set any property for bean. Part of code:

```
@Component("desktopBuilderCallback")
@Scope("prototype")
public class DesktopBuilderCallback implements BuilderCallback {

  private Socket desktopSocket;

  @Override
  public Transformation afterTransform(Transformation transformation)
      throws Exception {

           \\ some implementation
  }


  @Override
  public void handleStatusUpdate(Transformation transformation)
      throws Exception
      {
       \\ some implementation
      }


  public Socket getDesktopSocket() {
    return desktopSocket;
  }

  public void setDesktopSocket(Socket desktopSocket) {
    this.desktopSocket = desktopSocket;
  }
}


@Component("transformationBuilder")
@Scope("prototype")
public class TransformationBuilder implements Runnable,
SourceNotificationCallback, TargetNotificationCallback,
ApplicationContextAware {

   int test;
   BuilderCallback builderCallback;

   public BuilderCallback getBuilderCallback() {
      return builderCallback;
   }

   public void setBuilderCallback(BuilderCallback builderCallback) {
      this.builderCallback = builderCallback;
   }

   public int getTest() {
      return this.test;
   }

  public void setTest(int theTest) {
      this.test = theTest;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    TransformationBuilder transformationBuilder = (TransformationBuilder) ctx.getBean("transformationBuilder");

    DesktopBuilderCallback callback = (DesktopBuilderCallback) ctx.getBean("desktopBuilderCallback");
    transformationBuilder.setBuilderCallback(callback);  
    transformationBuilder.setTest(5);
}
```

After code executed, test and builderCallback will not be initialized. test will be 0 and builderCallback nil. Don't sure how it possible, I'm new in java and spring... , but I've checked that debugger jumps into setters (setTest, setBuilderCallback), maybe because project have been developed for JRE 1.5, but I'm using 1.8...

Comment: Where did you define `desktopBuilderCallback` ? Do you use XML configuration files or only annotations ? Show us the general definition of the `DesktopBuilderCallback` class, the answer may be there.

Comment: Also, where did you put that initialization code ?

Comment: Please add the code where you are checking for the beans to be properly initialized.

Comment: @CoffeeNinja have updated code.

Comment: Your updates don't give any new insights. If you call `ctx.getBean(...)` in a simple main method and you actually get a bean, the configuration and creation of the `ctx` would be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted so far I'd guess that your problem is related to the bean's scope being set to `prototype`.

From the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype):

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the creation of a **new bean instance every time a request for that specific bean is made** (that is, it is injected into another bean or it is requested via a programmatic getBean() method call on the container). As a rule of thumb, you should use the prototype scope for all beans that are stateful, while the singleton scope should be used for stateless beans.

That is every time you get the `transformationBuilder` bean from the application context (`ctx.getBean("transformationBuilder")`) you will get a **new instance** of the `TransformationBuilder`. Every manual initialization that is not part of the standard bean initialization process will get not be available in these instances.

To initialize your bean properly you can use the `@Value` annotation to inject values from your configuration, use `@Autowired` to inject other bean instances, or use `@PostConstruct` methods to perform additional, non-trivial initialization.

For your class this could look like this:

```
@Component("transformationBuilder")
@Scope("prototype")
public class TransformationBuilder implements Runnable,
        SourceNotificationCallback, TargetNotificationCallback,
        ApplicationContextAware {

   // either use the value of the property 'some.property.key' or 5 as default
   @Value("${some.property.key:5}")
   int test;

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("desktopBuilderCallback")
   BuilderCallback builderCallback;

   ...
}
```

Of course you could use the `singleton` scope (actually the default scope for spring beans) as well. This will result in the **same instance** to be returned by spring every time you request this bean. But with `singleton` scope the initialization of the bean should be handled by the DI-container as well.

Comment: i checks builderCallback value just after setBuilderCallback is executed. Also I've tried your suggest with Autowired earlier - without a luck. This part of code from the old project which seems was working earlier normally.

Comment: @toohtik considering the info you gave us, I don't think there can be a better answer than this one. There is probably something wrong with the way you're checking the values.

Comment: What do you mean - checking values? How I'm using debugger? Well, original issue that after this initialization, in somewhere later throws null pointer exception because trying to deal with builderCallback. Do you think that this problem couldn't be related with Spring/JDK/JRE version?

Comment: Where does it throw the `NullPointerException` ? Show us how you access the transformationBuilder bean. My guess is that you're doing `ctx.getBean("transformationBuilder")` again, which, as dpr explained, will get you a new object with uninitialized fields.

Comment: @toohtik Given the information you provided so far, there is nothing more to add to my answer. I doubt this problem is related to using JDK 1.8 instead of 1.5. But you can probably easily verify by using 1.5 again... If you want a better answer please provide a MVE.